# I need advice on ways to improve my kernel updater script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, kernel, gentoo

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

KERNEL_VERSION=$(echo /var/db/pkg/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources* | tr -d -c {0-9.})

cp /usr/src/linux/.config /usr/src/.config-"`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`"
cp -avL /usr/src/linux /tmp/linux
cd /tmp/linux

make clean
make -j8
make modules_install install

cp -avL /tmp/linux /usr/src/linux
cd /usr/src/linux

emerge @module-rebuild

dracut --hostonly -k /lib/modules/"$KERNEL_VERSION"-gentoo/ --kver "$KERNEL_VERSION"-gentoo -f /boot/initramfs-"$KERNEL_VERSION"-gentoo.img

grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Not copying /usr/src/linux to /tmp/linux (and then back again) would be a huge optimisation.   Do you not trust `make clean` or something?

Comment: @cas The point of copying to the tmpfs block is that it let's the kernel build inside ram which is much more faster as well as efficient. Make clean is just there as a precaution for the edge case where there are old symbols that may be left from building in /use/src/linux e.g. without the script.

Comment: I don’t see `/tmp/linux` being deleted/cleared out. If you have different versions copied over each other I wonder if that could cause an issue. Also, I think it’d be better to copy the results back to /usr/src/linux before doing modules_install because otherwise you will have modules and image installed which don’t refer to the contents of /usr/src/linux if there is a power failure. And the copy back doesn’t delete either. Maybe something like `rsync` with its `--delete` option would be better.

Comment: @Recompiler Sounds like premature optimisation to me, any benefit is more than offset by the time required to rsync the source to /tmp/linux.  If you must do it, just pre-cache the src files `find /usr/src/linux -type f -iname '*.[ch]' -exec cat {} + > /dev/null`.  It's still not worth the bother, but at least it doesn't waste RAM on files that don't need to be in a ramdisk.

Comment: I don't see any `make oldconfig` in the script, so are you making sure to track changes in the kernel options? They're usually irrelevant but sometimes have important options that you need to look at.